# How to run a foreground or background shell command in Go

Tags: go, exec, background-process

In Go, I need to be able to run a shell command from the user, and to only block for commands run in the foreground (not run with `&`), while retrieving the output of the command.

For example, in Bash we can have:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -p 'enter a command: ' cmd; do
    /bin/sh -c "$cmd" >(sed 's/^/line of output: /')
done
```

The user can enter a foreground command like `sleep 5; echo hi` and it will block and the prompt won't reappear instantly, or they can enter a background command like `{ sleep 5; echo hi; } &` and it won't block and the prompt will reappear instantly as the command runs in the background.

How would I recreate this in Go? Here is my attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for {
        print("enter a command: ")
        input.Scan()
        cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", input.Text())
        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go func() {
            output := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
            for output.Scan() {
                println("line of output: " + output.Text())
            }
            if output.Err() != nil {
                panic(output.Err())
            }
        }()
        if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Running `sleep 5; echo hi` blocks and works, but `{ sleep 5; echo hi; } &` errors with:

```
panic: read |0: file already closed
```

For context, I'm porting voice control to Go, where the user can configure actions such as `runtype`, where their command is run through the shell and keys are simulated to type the output. The user can use a background command so the voice control continues along with the command, for example, they can have it launch a menu when they say "menu" and still be able to use the voice control while it's open with: `menu: runtype printf %s\\n this that | dmenu &`.

Comment: What value are you trying to add by handling the input and output? You can get the desired effect by connecting the shell directly to stdin and stdout.

Comment: @JimB I've edited it to add context, I hope it helps but it's quite nice.

Comment: *niche not nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting stdout to a named pipe achieved the behavior.